# Compile error for Dim As Word.Range For Excel to Word Script

Tags: excel, vba, variables, ms-word

I am following along this youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URF3ikW0Svc) which allows me to write from excel to a word template. However having edited it for my needs I am getting an error early on when declaring one of the variables and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. The code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateWordDocumens()
Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow As Long
Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, FileName As String
Dim WordDoc As Object, WordApp As Object
Dim WordContent As Word.Range
With Sheet1

'Open Word Template
DocLoc = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
On Error Resume Next 'If Word is already running
Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'Launch a new instance of Word
Err.Clear
'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
End If

LastRow = .Range("B999").End(xlUp).Row 'Determine Last Row in Table
    For CustRow = 3 To LastRow
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
        For CustCol = 3 To 6 'Move Through the Columns
            TagName = .Cells(2, CustCol).Value 'Tag Name
            TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value 'Tag Value
            With WordDoc.Content.Find
                .Text = TagName
                .Replacement.Text = TagValue
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next CustCol
        
    If .Range("B2").Value = "PDF" Then
        FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("C3").Value & ".pdf" 'Create full file path and name
        WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=FileName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
        WordDoc.Close False
    Else
        FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("C3").Value & ".docx" 'Create full file path and name
        WordDoc.SaveAs FileName
    End If
    
Next CustRow
WordApp Quit
    
End With
End Sub
```

On line 5 of the subroutine ("Dim WordContent as Word.Range") I get compile error: User-defined type not defined, despite the fact this is exactly how the code is set up in the youtube tutorial. I do have the Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library referenced.

Any ideas why this may be happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a reference to the *Word* library.

Comment: Note that `Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow As Long` does only declare `LastRow As Long` but the first 2 variables `As Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable or it will be `Variant` by default: `Dim CustRow As Long, CustCol As Long, LastRow As Long` • You need to change that for all your variables.

Comment: @BigBen Is that not the Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library I stated? or is it a different one?

Comment: Different... Microsoft Word # Object Library.

Comment: Note that you're mixing late-binding: `Dim WordDoc As Object, WordApp As Object` and early-binding: `Dim WordContent As Word.Range`. It would be good to be consistent.

Comment: @BigBen that helped thank you although now nothing is happening when I run the script so will need to look into that. I will try be consistent thanks!

Comment: "Nothing is happening" ... `On Error Resume Next` is hiding the error.

Comment: @BigBen Yes Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application") seems to return automation error Invalid syntax